# Octave function to get groups of consecutive columns in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization, octave

I am trying to find an efficient way of extracting groups of *n* consecutive columns in a matrix. Example:

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4; 0, 1, 2, 3, 4; 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; 
n = 3;
```

should produce an output similar to this:

```
answer = cat(3, ...
                [0, 1, 2; 0, 1, 2; 0, 1, 2], ...
                [1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3], ...
                [2, 3, 4; 2, 3, 4; 2, 3, 4]);
```

I know this is possible using a `for` loop, such as the following code snippet:

```
answer = zeros([3, 3, 3]);
for i=1:3
  answer(:, :, i) = A(:, i:i+2);
endfor
```

However, I am trying to avoid using a `for` loop in this case - is there any possibility to vectorize this operation as well (using indexed expressions)?

Comment: Using `blockproc` you can do something like this: `answer = reshape(blockproc(A,[n,1],[0,1],@(x) x),n,n,[])(:,:,2:end-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using just indexing

```
ind = reshape(1:size(A,1)*n, [], n) + reshape((0:size(A,2)-n)*size(A,1), 1, 1, []); 
result = A(ind);
```

The index `ind` is built using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/).

## Using the Image Package / Image Processing Toolbox

```
result = reshape(im2col(A, [size(A,1) n], 'sliding'), size(A,1), n, []);
```

Most of the work here is done by the [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) function with the `'sliding'` option.

Comment: This has the expected result, I will test the second option too.